# How to change specific part of a string?

Tags: python-3.x, string

For example, I have a string like this

```
a = "starlight sunlight"
```

And I want to change it into

```
a = "starspot sunspot"
```

Comment: `.replace` it? Have you done any research?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well i guessed you writing this in python so you can use the replace method
[enter example](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp)

in your case you went to replace the word light with the word spot so just write

```
a=a.replace("light","post")
```